# Cardinality exercise.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Prove that there is an injective function $ \phi: \mathcal P (A) \to \mathcal{P} (\mathcal {P} (A)) $.

What I did was define an injective function $  \psi: A \to \mathcal P (A) $ given by $ \psi (x) = \{x \} $.

Then define the function $ \phi: \mathcal P (A) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) $ given by $$ \phi (A) = \{\psi (a) \mid a \in A \} $$ The $ \phi $ function will be injective. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, If $\phi(A)=\phi(B)$, then $\{\psi(a)\mid a\in A\}=\{\psi(b)\mid b\in B\}$. We then should have $A=B$, but don't forget to check the details. Nonetheless, I am curious about what $(\ mathcalP(A))$ means.

Comment: Given that $\psi: X \to \mathscr{P}(X)$ defined by $\psi(x) = \{x\}$ is invective for any set $X$, apply this to the set $X = \mathscr{P}(A)$.